# How can you store JSP buffered output from an include/import to a variable?

Tags: jsp, jstl, buffer

I don't want to use any Java code, I just want to use `<jsp:include>` or `<c:import>` or something to that effect. So that I can use

```
<c:set var="myPage" value="bufferedPageOutput" />
```

to output the generated HTML later.

How can I do this with JSP/JSTL/Struts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<c:import>` tag can take an optional `var` attribute, which stores the imported content as a variable.

```
<c:import var="myPage" url="uri/to/import"/>
```

[Very useful](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~slonnegr/wpj/jqr.pdf)

Comment: Can be shortened to `<c:import var="myPage" url="uri/to/import"/>` :)