# What's the equivalent to ob_get_contents (PHP) in JSP?

Tags: php, jsp

When i create a master page in PHP i use:

```
<?
ob_start();
?>
HTML
<?
$PAGE_CONTENT = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
include "master.page.php";
?>
```

So i change the content put it in a variable and print it in master.page.php.

I now need to do the same thing with JSP. What is the equivalent?
I'm new with JSP, it is for a work and i need help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563735/how-can-you-store-jsp-buffered-output-from-an-include-import-to-a-variable

Comment: Hi @RoyalBg perhaps i didn't understand, cause as i said, i'm new with jsp, but i'm not trying to load the content of a file, i'm trying to create content in html and put it in a variable...

Comment: You'll have to use JSTL. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/beagw/index.html and http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/05/jspcache.html Its a bit more involved than in PHP. You have to edit the web.xml as well.

Comment: Thank you @developerwjk i'll try it and then i'll sy something.